# UIScrollView clickable images iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, uiscrollview

I have created a UIScrollView in my app - adapted from this sample code: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html

But I have no idea how to make the images clickable

Any suggestions please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah... "Put them on UIButtons"

```
//get the image to use, however you want
UIImage* image = [product.images objectAtIndex:i];

UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] init];

//set the button states you want the image to show up for
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

//create the touch event target, i am calling the 'productImagePressed' method
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(productImagePressed:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//i set the tag to the image #, i was looking though an array of them
button.tag = i;
//add the new button w/ the image to your scrollview 
[ImagesScroller addSubview:button];
[button release];
```

Comment: the image doesn't get displayed at all when I try this method

Answer (score 2):

Put them on UIButtons.